# Why do European motorized appliances draw less inrush current than their American counterparts?

Tags: motor, design, circuit-protection, inrush-current, appliances

I have been trying to tease apart the history and evolution of arc fault circuit interrupter *requirements*, and in the process, came across a curious historical sidenote early in its genesis, namely that the use of a 5x-or-so (IEC "B" curve) magnetic trip on general branch circuit breakers is [said to serve as](http://web.archive.org/web/20180815021241/http://paceforensic.com/pdfs/Circuit_Breakers_The_Myth_of_Safety.pdf) a highly effective fire prevention means.  This was followed up on by EIA with a proposal in the 1996 NEC, but according to [a UL whitepaper](https://legacy-uploads.ul.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/40/2015/02/BreakerMitigationofArcFaults.pdf), the proposal was rejected due to concerns about inrush from tungsten and motor loads.  However, [according to this article](https://www.elecmagazine.com/selecting-the-right-mcb-or-rcbo/), said IEC "B" curve breakers are considered "generally suitable for domestic applications" in at least some countries utilizing IEC-derived wiring standards, with "C" curve breakers (8x-10x magnetic trip) reserved for dedicated motor loads or other high-inrush situations (such as magnetic LV lighting transformers) in the domestic context.

This raises a question, though: why is it that the North American market seems unable to utilize magnetic trip thresholds below 7x-10x (roughly "C" curve, and generally equivalent to a QO's magnetic trip, at least on 15/20A single pole breakers)?  Is it simply a matter of "half the voltage = twice the motor inrush," or is there some deeper reason that domestic motorized appliances made for the rest of the planet have a lower inrush current than their North American counterparts?

Comment: NB: the reason I'm asking this here and not on DIY.SE is because I'm trying to get insight from the appliance-design (or small-motor-design) side of the picture here -- I have read enough of what electricians have to say about it to not need any more answers from that side of the house!

Comment: This looks like voltage v current and the changing resistance or inductance  between devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Is it simply a matter of "half the voltage = twice the motor inrush"*

Yes it is. For a given load power, the current taken by a load in the US will be about 2.1x higher than an equivalent load in the UK.

This not only applies to continuous load current but inrush current too.